# Uploading Laravel Project onto Web Server

Tags: laravel, upload, webserver, web-hosting

I am trying to upload my Laravel project onto my web server, but my past two attempts have been unsuccessful. I believe I am not uploading the files to the right location.

This is my web server's structure -> [image: WebServer Structure]

Am I correct to say that I need to upload ALL of my laravel files into public_html?

This is my Laravel project's directory :

[image: Laravel Project Directory]

EDIT : I have now added all the files onto the root folder, and public into public_html, however none of my routes seem to work. (They work perfectly on localhost). Everything throws a 404

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, but you have a couple of options:

The easiest is to upload all the files you have into that directory you're in (i.e. the cPanel user home directory), and put the contents of public into public_html. That way your directory structure will be something like this (slightly messy but it works):

```
/
    .composer/
    .cpanel/
    ...
    app/                 <- your laravel app directory
    etc/
    bootstrap/           <- your laravel bootstrap directory
    mail/
    public_html/         <- your laravel public directory
    vendor/
    artisan              <- your project's root files
```

You may also need to edit `bootstrap/paths.php` to point at the correct public directory.

The other solution, if you don't like having all these files in that 'root' directory would be to put them in their own directory (maybe 'laravel') that's still in the root directory and then edit the paths to work correctly. You'll still need to put the contents of `public` in `public_html`, though, and this time edit your `public_html/index.php` to correctly bootstrap the application. Your folder structure will be a lot tidier this way (though there could be some headaches with paths due to messing with the framework's designed structure more):

```
/
    .composer/
    .cpanel/
    ...
    etc/
    laravel/      <- a directory containing all your project files except public
        app/
        bootstrap/
        vendor/
        artisan
    mail/
    public_html/  <- your laravel public directory
```

Comment: i will +1 this for the 1st approach. the system files should be taken out of public access.

Comment: I put everything into the folder as you said, and put public into public_html, but now I'm getting this error when I visit my domain -

`View [layouts.main] not found. `

Comment: @itachi I actually meant for the second approach that the system files would *also* be out of the public folder, will edit the post to clarify.

Comment: @SainathKrishnan all I can say here is that you really need to check that all your paths are set up as correctly as possible. There are a few places where Laravel sets up paths, although the main two are `public/index.php` and `bootstrap/paths.php` but the view stuff is in `app/config/view.php` so maybe check that out too if you're having view issues. I guess also ensure that the `app/storage/` directory (and all directories within it) are somehow writable by the process that runs PHP for that site.

Comment: My issue was due to there being a duplicate .htaccess file, got it fixed now. Thank you for your original solution! Cheers :)

Comment: I have answered to a similar question for uploading a laravel 5 project to shared hosting with step by step instructions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461322/upload-laravel-5-to-server-subfolder/35474800#35474800

Comment: I do not understand why we can take this solution. I think this not helpful at much. Yes it may works but we change some rule there. Why we change ?

Comment: Laravel (at least at the time of writing this answer) just wouldn't work like this without the extra work required to make it do so. As you can see by how short the answer is though, Laravel was set up to allow these kinds of changes be made. Sometimes you have to put a little work in to go against a default, that's just the way of life. It's worth me pointing out, however, that the solution I ended up sticking with for this kind of thing was to put *all* of the Laravel stuff (un-renamed) in a directory `src/` and then symlink `public_html` to `src/public/`.

Comment: How did you symlink it? Can you please provide the answer to that here?

Comment: @KevinRED sorry for the delay, and I'm almost certainly waaay too late here, but you'd have to symlink it by going to the command line on your shared host and running, from the root of your hosting (where `public_html` would sit) `ln -s src/public public_html` (or, more generically, `ln -s path/to/thing-you-actually-have where-you-want-it-to-pretened-it-is`). You might find that you already have a `public_html` set up by the hosting, you should just be able to delete that directory and add the link in, and then you may need to change the permissions on that new `public_html` using `chmod -h`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: i uploaded my project to public_html and it's not working for now i wanted to know is there a way to solve my issue without changing .htaccess file or the structure of my project ?

Answer (score 13):

I believe - your `Laravel` `files/folders` should not be placed in root directory.

e.g. If your domain is pointed to `public_html` directory then all content should placed in that directory. How ? let me tell you

1. Copy all files and folders ( including `public` folder ) in `public_html`
2. Copy all content of public folder and paste it in document root ( i.e. `public_html` )
3. Remove the `public` folder
4. Open your `bootstrap/paths.php` and then changed `'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',` into `'public' => __DIR__.'/..',`
5. and finally in `index.php`,

**Change**

> ```
> require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
>
> $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
> ```

**into**

> ```
> require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
>
> $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';
> ```

Your `Laravel` application should work now.

Comment: The whole point of Laravel's public folder is that everything else is NOT in it.

Comment: i am following this step but still nothing to display can any one help me please. i am using laravel 4 it is working in local perfectly.

Comment: There is no file named paths.php in bootstrap folder.  How do I get it?

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to host your Laravel app on a shared hosting, this may help you.

[Hosting Laravel on shared hosting #1](http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host/)

[Hosting Laravel on shared hosting #2](http://juniorgrossi.com/2012/deploying-laravel-applications-on-a-shared-host/)

If you want PHP 5.4 add this line to your `.htaccess` file or call your hosting provider.

`AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php`

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5.x there is no `paths.php`

so you should edit `public/index.php` and change this lines in order to to pint to your `bootstrap` directory:

```
require __DIR__.’/../bootstrap/autoload.php’;

$app = require_once __DIR__.’/../bootstrap/app.php’;
```

for more information you can read [this](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e) article.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem too and found out that the easiest way is to point your domain to the public folder and leave everything else the way they are.

PLEASE ENSURE TO USE THE RIGHT VERSION OF PHP. Save yourself some stress :)

Comment: In your cPanel navigate to Select PHP version and in that you have set your PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

All of your Laravel files should be in one location.
Laravel is exposing its **public** folder to server. That folder represents some kind of front-controller to whole application. Depending on you server configuration, you have to point your server path to that folder. As I can see there is **www** site on your picture. **www** is default root directory on Unix/Linux machines. 
It is best to take a look inside you server configuration and search for root directory location. As you can see, Laravel has already file called **.htaccess**, with some ready Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If you are uploading in Cpanel or cloud make sure exact version of laravel, php should be taken care.

(2) Make changes in .env files with refrence to DB credentials user and pass if in localhost