# Laravel 5 - removing /public from URL

Tags: laravel

I am pointing everything into /public folder with this .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

It is fine, i can load /administration path without /public, but the problem is, that i can also load it like this /public/administration.

Comment: I have previously answered a very similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server/22075459#22075459, albeit for Laravel 4 so I don't know if it is still applicable to Laravel 4, but I imagine it is.

Comment: I also had same problem with Laravel 5. This solution worked for me. http://justcode.me/laravel/remove-public-index-php-url-generated-laravel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it looks like your virtual host config is pointing to the directory above `public`. Why? Do you need it to be this way for some reason?

Laravel should work out of the box with Apache provided your document root is set to the public dir. That's why there's a default .htaccess inside that directory.

Comment: Thanks for information, but this is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Why isn't it? What's stopping you from changing your document root?

Comment: On my localhost i can do it, but on hosting i have got access just only for web. I am trying to achieve this on hosting, on localhost i use artisan serve.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I assume none of the answers here help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url

Comment: Changing the structure is not recommended, but i have tried it. And i also tried to point with .htaccess.

Comment: What did you end up doing? Did this work or not. I see you accepted the answer, but in the comments you explain that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this alternative `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Source: [Laravel Documentation's §Installation > #Pretty Urls](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2#pretty-urls)

Comment: This is .htaccess within /public, i am trying to point from root directly to /public, so i cannot use this .htaccess.