# 404 Error in Laravel 5.1 deployment

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my first Laravel deployment. I deployed to my test server (Ubuntu Server) and I keep getting 404 on all my pages except for the default page. When I change the default route, my current default page displayed and every other pages returns 404. Here's my deployment guide: [Uploading Laravel Project onto Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server). I used the second answer on the link as my guide.
Here's my Route that works,

```
Route::get('dashboard','AdminController@index');
Route::get('/','AdminController@index');
```

But,

```
Route::get('users/roles','RolesController@index');
Route::post('addrole','RolesController@store');
```

and every other route failed, returning 404. 
Here's my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index/.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

All of this works while on my localhost while running `php artisan serve`

I also did a server scenario on my localhost, I mean restructure the folders to suite my deployment guide and I still got the same thing -

> **Not found** The requested URL /tezza/public/auth/login was not found on
>   this server.

The funny thing is that it worked before I restructured the folders in such manner.

Comment: You need to share some code and some more info on what you're trying to do. This is really a bad question.

Comment: If you need more clarity, I'll give.

Comment: Need to compare your Local machine vs Deploy server configs to solve this, is the stack the same? IP's / URL's? What about your .env file? So many things could be the culprit

Comment: What type of 404 is it a server 404 or is it the laravel application returning the 404?

Comment: @MatthewRath, what about the .env file? I think that's just for database config.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your server setup but the below is what works for me.

In my site root folder ( on my server it is called default) I have this htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and in my Laravel "public" folder root I have another htaccess as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Perhaps that will help?

Comment: Downvoter, if you are going to downvote please at least be civil enough to give a reason.