# Upload Laravel 5 to server subfolder

Tags: laravel, upload, server, subdirectory

I am trying to upload Laravel 5 project to subfolder as:

> > public_html/project/

I have changed in index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/app.php';
```

in config/app.php

```
'url' => 'http://example.com/project',
```

when I try url as:
http://example.com/project/public it is directed to 
http://example.com/public

What is the way to upload it to server. Can anyone help me as I have tried lot options.

Comment: Change your project root directory as `public_html/project/public`. You don't have to change anything else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not a good idea to upload your entire laravel project in the public_html (public)folder. The files in the public folder are having unrestricted access.

If you are constrained to think about uploading the laravel project to the public_html folder because you want to upload to a shared host, then it is not necessary to do so.
Instead try this:
1. Create a folder called laravel (or anything you like) on the same level as the public_html folder.

```
Eg:  
/
 |--var  
    |---www
        |----laravel
        |----public_html
```

2. Copy every thing except the `public` folder from your laravel project in the `laravel` folder (on server host).
3. Open the public folder of your laravel project, copy everything and paste in the `public_html` folder (on server host)
4.  Now open the `index.php` file in the `public_html` folder and:

```
Change:  
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';  
To:  
requrie require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';  
And  
Change: 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';  
To:  
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';  
Save and close.
```

5.  Now go to the `laravel` folder and open `server.php` file

```
Change:  
require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';  
To:  
require_once __DIR__.'../public_html/index.php'; 
Save and close.
```

Now when you visit the url which you configured as the domain with your server, your laravel app should work just as it worked on your localhost.

Note: The `'url'=>'someurl'`  in the `config/app` is used by artisan ie the cli, it does not have any effect on your webserver urls.
Hope it helps.

**Edit**
After completing the above if your get a blank page when you try to visit the url, set write permissions for the storage folder recursively .i.e all folders within the storage and its subfolders should have permissions `775` set for the webserver owner and group to have write permission.

You can also set the permissions as `777` to give read, write and execute access to all for the storage folder if you don't plan to store any sensitive information in the storage folder.

Be careful with the file permissions in linux, they are like double edged sword, if not used correctly, they may make your app vulnerable to attacks.  For understanding Linux file permissions you can read [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)

Comment: Thanks. I did as you have said but now I am getting a blank page. I have given read/write access to storage, vendor and bootstrap>cache. What would be the error.

Comment: This normally happens due to missing write permission to storage. Please ensure that each of the folders within the storage folder and all its sub folders have write permissions for the webserver group or user. Sometimes one can easily forget to set write permissions recursively i.e the storage folder itself would have the write permission but its subfolders would not have write permissions. Verify. Also if you use devtools does it show any errrors?

Comment: This worked for me. But I was using Laravel 5.5.13 and I didn't realize it, but I had to set (1) PHP to >= 7.0 && (2) make sure to give MySQL database user permissions on the database && (3) make sure to do a manual php migrate (export from local and import to remote). I didn't have to set permissions to 777 thankfully.

Comment: I also had change `DB_HOST`, `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME`, and `DB_PASSWORD` in `.env` file. And from cPanel, create database, create the user, and then importantly add the user to the database with permissions I gave it "All Privileges".

Answer (score 1):

After I completed the above steps. Do check with read/write permissions(i.e it should be 777) for few folcers:

storage, vendor and bootstrap>cache

Check for .htaccess file if it is there in the public_html folder or copy it from public folder.

Finally check the version of php it should be higher than 5.5

It worked for me. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Issue Fixed:-

Go to laravelFolder/bootstrap/cache then rename config.php 
eg. config.php_old and reload your site.

Answer (score -1):

I did like this. (My version was laravel 5.2)

1. Change the name of server.php file to 'index.php'.
2. Copy .htaccess file from public folder to main directory(Created subfolder)
3. And inside .htaccess after **RewriteEngine On** we have to add 
   RewriteBase /yoursubfolder/