# Path for images for Laravel project from cpanel

Tags: laravel, path, cpanel

I have a problem with displaying pictures in View for my project in Laravel..destination path in my application where the photos were saved is: public_path (/ images) but recently I put the project on the server in cpanel, and to get rid of / public from the url, I used a google article, and I made a folder called laravel outside the public_html folder, in which I keep the application files and in public_html I keep only the files that were in the public folder of the application. In View I display the pictures as follows: "{{asset ('images /'. $ Img-> file_name)}}" .. Only it is no longer displayed. Pictures are saved but no longer displayed. I mention that it is saved in the Laravel folder which is outside the public_html folder..and I think that public / images was created automatically there..I would like to know if anyone has faced such a thing and what is the solution. thank you

Comment: You need to make a sym link with your `root/public_html/public` path to `root/laravel/public`

Comment: @sta i guess you can do that but that sounds vague. OP should probably just read `public_html` as `public` instead. Theyre 2 different names for the same thing, depending on how you have apache configured.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461322/upload-laravel-5-to-server-subfolder/35474800#35474800 written in 2016.

Comment: @Donkarnash it's not enough. ..is created: public / images in laravel_project folder and saved there..instead of public_html / public / images

Comment: I guess the images folder should be within public_html : `public_html/images` and once `require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';` is changed to `require_once __DIR__.'../public_html/index.php';` it works

Comment: @Donkarnash yes i have public_html/images and in server.php I changed require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php' to __DIR__.'../public_html/index.php';...
Should I change if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri))  to if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public_html'.$uri)) ???

Comment: Sorry my bad server.php is just to emulate apache mod_rewrite when testing via php artisan serve i.e on in-built php server. Can't figure out any reason why it shouldn't work. What is the output of `asset ('images /'. $ Img-> file_name)` - any thing different? Does `php artisan clear-compiled` make any difference

Comment: @Donkarnash I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:
In AppServiceProvider in register() I put this code:

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function () {
        return base_path('../public_html');
    });
```

and now I have public_html/images and there my images are saved..and the rest of myy app, outside public_html folder in a different folder named laravel_project

Comment: This is an amazing trick. Mark your answer as accepted

Comment: How do you reference your images in a blade template

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8, I solved it adding this to the /app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php in register method:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function () {
        return base_path('../public_html');
    });
}
```

But in order to create the symlink from the "php artisan storage:link" command, I also had to add this code to /bootstrap/app.php, just after the last singleton:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function () {
    return base_path("../public_html");
});
```

Finally I used this code to get the image that will be sent to my blade template:

```
$image=Storage::disk('public')->url('path_to_image');
```