# hosting a laravel 5.1 application in live server

Tags: laravel-5.1

I installed **laravel 5.1** on **my local system** and *developed* an application.

Now I have to **host** it on **a live server**. The live server we have is our own and has many other applications running on it.

I have just placed the laravel folder in a path now (nothing else), but it's not working as I expected.

I have read some answers that said I have to **copy the public folder** to the **server's public folder** and the rest to a folder - is that correct?

Do I have to **install composer** and follow the laravel installation process there also?

Can anyone please explain what I have to do to make it work there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading Laravel Project onto Web Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server)

Answer (score 2):

Of course you have to install composer in there in order to run composer install, update and other commands.

All instruction are already written in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @davejal, Thanks for the suggestion. But in our server, the php version is 5.3.3 and laravel needs 5.5.9 up. As i said, we have many other core php apps running in same server, will there be any problem for them after upgrading php? I got this threat by someone ......."On update of php version,  php-mysqlnd will replace existing php-mysql. Pls check and confirm that the new package will not break the existing code".  WIll there be any such severity?

Comment: @vikram I didn't answer, I only edited. But check the link I provided as a comment right under your question.

Comment: Oh Yes!, Sorry, anyways, can you please help me in solving the problem of understanding severity while upgrading php?