# Laravel - Uploading all files required?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Today I wanted to move one of my projects from my development environment to my productive one.

When I tried to upload it via FTP I already saw almost 110k files being updated.

Can anyone tell me if this is really required or do I miss some compromizing functions etc. to get it up and running?

Cheers,
Fabian

Comment: take a look this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have the restrictions like some of the shared hosting account, where you are not allowed to install composer or do not have shell access all together then you don't require to upload the `vendor` directory as mentioned by @djt above - you can run `composer install` on your production server which will populate the vendor directory with all dependencies.

`node_nodules` folder can also be safely excluded from the ftp uploads, since mostly it contains dependencies for development purpose only. In case you require any of the node_modules for production then with a similar approach, you can just upload the `package.json` file to your production server and then run `npm install` to get all the node_modules installed on your production server.

The `vendor` and `node_modules` directories are the most bulky, excluding them from ftp will ensure that you are uploading only your application/project code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be uploading your 'vendor' directory.

So you should exclude that directory in the FTP upload and run 'composer install' on the new server. This will download your dependencies into the 'vendor' directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) Worked fine.

Comment: @Astinox no problem. Please mark it Answered so others know!