# How to upload the laravel 5.2.42 project to cPannel?

Tags: php, laravel, web, cpanel

please guide me how to upload the Laravel project to my cPanel I am very much confused.

Comment: What did you try so far please ?

Comment: Make sure you understand what cPanel mean? If not take a research how to use it

Comment: I added the public folder files to public_html and other than public folder i added into the root and i changes the index.php as said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server?answertab=active#tab-top but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please describe what you are doing step by step in your post, what you expect to happen and what actually happens (see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and may be http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

you should add all the folders of laravel inside of public_html folder, and you need to move index.php and .htaccess file to the public_html directory from public directory. Now make changes index.php like this.

require **DIR**.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/start.php';

That may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your laravel project, there is a `public` folder inside it.

By default, your domain is pointed at the `root level` or on `public_html`. On you cPanel Domain settings, make sure your domain is pointed your Laravel application `public` folder.