# Laravel 5.2 Routes Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, vps, laravel-artisan

I just moved a homestead laravel installation to my own vps setup.

Everything is working fine on the homepage (**XX.XX.XX.XX/public**).

But when i click ay links on the homepage it goes to **XX.XX.XX.XX/link** 
instead of **XX.XX.XX.XX/public/link** as i whould think it should.

I have a local setup with homestead and a link like this one XX.XX.XX.XX/signin whould work fine.

And when i try XX.XX.XX.XX/public/signin on the vps it gives a 404 error.

In my sites-available i have setup the below .conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName XX.XX.XX.XX/app.domain.dk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/app.domain.dk/public

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/app.domain.dk/public>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

What could be the problem, please help me : )

Comment: can you test this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server

Comment: Im not using shared hosting, so i put everything in var/www/myfolder, what should i test?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in wrongly configured web server. You should [point web server to a `laravel_project/public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) and use URLs like `XX.XX.XX.XX/link` instead of `XX.XX.XX.XX/public/link`.

For Apache you can use these directives:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
```

Don't forget to restart web server.

Comment: Hi Alexey Mezening, i have just updated my post to contain my .conf file, can you see any problems with it? :)

Comment: Did you restart Apache? If yes, what do you get now when you go to `XX.XX.XX.XX/signin`?

Comment: Is the same it gives me a 404 error, i used this to restart sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

I figured out i was missing a forward slash in my .conf file.

So it should be **/var/www/app.domain.dk/public/**

Thanks for the help everybody :)