# Uploading Laravel Project into the Web Server

Tags: laravel, hosting, web-hosting

I have the folder into the web server `/`, where I put all the files/folders except the public folder(with that index.php) of the new laravel project and also in `/public_html/` I put all the files from the public folder.

I didn't have to change the paths in bootstrap folder containing 2 files app and autoload, and I did everything as is in the first path in 
[Uploading Laravel Project onto Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server)

Instead of showing the notorious Welcome to Laravel, it shows nothing.

I am using godaddy web hosting. What I am doing wrong?

**Solution:**

**1.**
You have the Home Directory in the web server

```
/
```

Which is the parent of Public_HTML folder, here you upload into a folder created by you all the files contenting your laravel project files, folders except the public folder.

In the

```
/Public_html
```

You upload all the files containing in the public folder of your laravel project

**2.** Open the index.php into the public_html and change these things:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

into

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravelfoldernameinroot/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravelfoldernameinroot/bootstrap/app.php';
```

**3.** Make sure to change the php version in cpanel into 5.6, this is obligatory in order the website to work.

**4.** All other changes depends on changes you made after building the fresh laravel project.

Comment: * it shows error 500 (check console)

Comment: why is this happening? I am not very used to console. What should I do?

Comment: this is just fresh laravel project created with the composer on localhost(xampp), verified, and put it on server, just for testing, not the real project, just testing

Comment: most likely server does not have access to files (permission problem)

Comment: everything 0755 from laravel, should i change it with filezilla

Comment: I am confused you have problem on godad on on localhost?

Comment: on my domain with godaddy, on localhost everything is amazing, on godaddy is just blank page

Comment: try `chgrp -R www-data storage` & is your `.env` file there? Check your error logs

Comment: I changed the permissions and env file is there, doesn't work either, how to check error logs

Comment: what's your php version on Godaddy server? Laravel 5.3 requires php 5.6.

Comment: Have you resolved the problem ?

Comment: yup, the solution I put in the edited post