# Run laravel project on existing apache server(production) of centos

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos, production-environment

I have a server of CentOs 7 where apache is running. I'm using it for run my web applications. Now I want to run a laravel 5.0 project on it. I know its weird but reality is I'm new at laravel and this server php version is so old 5.4. So I can't use newest version of laravel on this server.

My laravel project running well at my localhost. Now I need to deploy it to my production server without artisan command. URL will be https://server-ip/laravel-project. But I don't know how to do it.

I'm trying some suggestions from google search but not working. When I go to https://server-ip/laravel-project its shows

> **403 Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /laravel-project on this server.

Please give me proper solution to do it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try https://my-server-ip/my-laravel-project/public/

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: this link can be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075238/uploading-laravel-project-onto-web-server

Answer (score 1):

Give the permissions to the directory, here is the command
`chmod -R 655 path/to/directory` to give proper permission to folder and files.

Comment: Thank you, removed the comment